# What port do I use to send MQTT messages to FairCom MQ from Python?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, faircom

I'm trying to send MQTT messages to FairCom MQ using Paho. What port would I use?

In my paho.mqtt.publish() call I understand to set hostname to "localhost" or the IP of the machine FairCom MQ is running on but what do I set port to?

Answer (score 1):

1883 is the default port for MQTT in general. FairCom MQ defaults to this port, so if you have not changed the MQTT port by editing cthttpd.json in the config folder use 1883. I.E.

paho.mqtt.publish(topic, payload="My payload", qos=0, hostname="localhost", port=1883)